# Get the Count of not null date from the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sum

This feels like it should be an easy one. How do I get the Count of cell where dates that are in not null in different columns.

```
DROP TABLE #indebtedness
CREATE TABLE #indebtedness (call_case CHAR(10), date1 DATETIME, date2 DATETIME, date3 DATETIME)
INSERT #indebtedness VALUES ('Key1', '2019-10-30', '2019-11-30',      null   )
INSERT #indebtedness VALUES ('Key2',   NULL      ,     null    , '2019-10-15')
INSERT #indebtedness VALUES ('Key3', '2019-11-11', '2019-10-29', '2019-10-30')
INSERT #indebtedness VALUES ('Key4',     null    , '2019-10-29', '2019-10-13')
```

I would like the result to be:

```
call_case    NOT NULL
Key1            2 
Key2            1 
Key3            3
Key4            2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```sql
SELECT 
  call_case, 
  CASE WHEN date1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN date2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
    CASE WHEN date3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  AS "NOT NULL"
FROM indebtedness
;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are many and you don't want to hard-code them or to make a complex logic - for example check columns with particular type or name, you can use the system views to build such dynamic expression.

In your case:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.indebtedness
CREATE TABLE dbo.indebtedness (call_case CHAR(10), date1 DATETIME, date2 DATETIME, date3 DATETIME)
INSERT dbo.indebtedness VALUES ('Key1', '2019-10-30', '2019-11-30',      null   )
INSERT dbo.indebtedness VALUES ('Key2',   NULL      ,     null    , '2019-10-15')
INSERT dbo.indebtedness VALUES ('Key3', '2019-11-11', '2019-10-29', '2019-10-30')
INSERT dbo.indebtedness VALUES ('Key4',     null    , '2019-10-29', '2019-10-13')


DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                    SELECT ' + CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(C.[name]) + 'IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'
                                    FROM [sys].[columns] C
                                    INNER JOIN [sys].[types] T
                                        ON C.[system_type_id] = T.[system_type_id]
                                    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.indebtedness')
                                        AND T.[name] = 'datetime'
                                    ORDER BY C.[name]
                                    FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,3
                                ,''
                          );

SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = 'SELECT call_case, ' + @DynamicColumns + ' AS [NOT NULL] FROM dbo.indebtedness;'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bring the three columns into line using a union, and then leverage the `COUNT` function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT call_case, date1 AS date FROM #indebtedness UNION ALL
    SELECT call_case, date2 FROM #indebtedness UNION ALL
    SELECT call_case, date3 FROM #indebtedness
)

SELECT
    call_case,
    COUNT(date) AS [NOT NULL]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    call_case;
```

Actually, if you have long term needs for queries similar to this, it might imply that your data model should change, and that you should just have a single date column.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite tricky due to `null` values, i used `sql server` `min` date `17530101` basis of these null values.

```
select call_case, iif(coalesce(date1, '17530101')='17530101', 0, 1) 
    + iif(coalesce(date2, '17530101')='17530101', 0, 1) 
    + iif(coalesce(date3, '17530101')='17530101', 0, 1) from
#indebtedness
```

**or**

```
select call_case, iif(isnull(date1,0)=0, 0, 1) 
    + iif(isnull(date2,0)=0, 0, 1) 
    + iif(isnull(date3,0)=0, 0, 1)  from
#indebtedness
```